# How Can I Implement the Grid-like Control Using C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, controls

I need a control like this:

[image]

This is from the Microsoft Word: Insert => Symbols.

1. This dialog has a grid-like control with a list of Unicode Characters;
2. You can select any character;
3. The selected character's Unicode is displayed;
4. User cannot edit the character;

Besides, I need to extend it's feature:
1. User can delete the cell with the selected character;
2. User can add a list of characters (from a file or whatever).

I'm asking what built-in controls I should use to implement this specific control.

Thanks.

Peter

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.Net? Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a simple mock up using the standard [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) control.

[image: DataGridView]

```
private void InitilizeDataGridView(DataGridView view)
{
    var defaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();

    defaultCellStyle.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
    defaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False;
    defaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
    defaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
    defaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
    defaultCellStyle.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    defaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((0)));

    view.DefaultCellStyle = defaultCellStyle;

    view.MultiSelect = false;
    view.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    view.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    view.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
    view.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
    view.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    view.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
    view.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;

    view.BackgroundColor = SystemColors.Control;

    for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {              
        view.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill, Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False });
    }

    DataGridViewRow row = null;

    for (int index = 32, cell = 0; index < 255; index++, cell++)
    {
        if(cell % 16 == 0)
        {
            if(row != null)
            {
                view.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            row = new DataGridViewRow { Height = 40 };
            row.CreateCells(view);

            cell = 0;
        }

        if (row != null)
        {
            row.Cells[cell].Value = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(index);
        }               
    }            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I was actually trying the DataGridView, and it looks fine.  The first problem is: if you want to delete one of them, everything after that character needs to be shifted; The second problem is: if the width of the control changed, it's very difficult to increase the number of columns, because it's a 2-dimension control (FlowLayoutPanel works cooler in this case, but FlowLayoutPanel is not the best choice due to other issues).

Comment: Anyway, I will try your suggestion again.  The UI looks-n-feel and event handling using DataGridView seems the best choice :-)

Comment: I implemented using DataGridView. As far, it looks pretty good.  I have a question: how to NOT display the blank cells? Say if there are only 20 characters, but a row must have 16 characters, so the 2nd row should only have 4 characters.  but I don't know how to not display the extra 12 blank cells. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms, you can add fixed-size `Label` controls to a `FlowLayoutPanel` at runtime.

Note that this will not scale well; do not make thousands of Label controls.
If you want large numbers of characters, you can make a single screenfull of labels, then add a ScrollBar control and handle the Scroll event to change the label captions.

Comment: I was also trying to use FlowLayoutPanel, but there are a lot of stuff I have to implement myself: such as Arrow keys move, select....